# How to call value from getter and setter method

Tags: c#, methods, setter, getter

I have a class called nyoba, i tried to enter value of textBox1.Text to eek.konsentrasi.
And I don't have any idea to call value of eek.konsentrasi from another class. Anybody knows? please help me.

```
 public class nyoba
    {
        private string Konsentrasi;
        public string konsentrasi
        {
            get
            {
                return Konsentrasi;
            }
            set
            {
                Konsentrasi = value;
            }
        }
        public void njajal(string hehe)
        {

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nyoba eek = new nyoba();
        eek.konsentrasi = textBox1.Text;
    }


public class caller
{
//how to get eek.konsentrasi variable?
}
```

Comment: You can't since no `caller` instance has been initialized yet. You can implement in that class a costructor and pass the value you want to.

Comment: Both the button click event and the "caller" method must share the very same instance of nyoba. Storing it in a class level variable seems like a good starting point.

Comment: That button click event is totally wrong placed in the code example. You should provide for information, too.

Answer (score 1):

As first, your class names should always be pascal case (first letter uppercase). Also your **public** property should be pascal case.
Then your Nyoba class and its property Konsentrasi are not static, means you have to initiate the class as object before you can access it's non static property.

```
Nyoba n = new Nyoba();
string s = n.Konsentrasi;
```

To access the same instance you should not create the instance inside of the button click event. Place your Nyoba instance somewhere you can access to in the form and in the Caller class.

Comment: You mean [PascalCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx) .